# Texture works in one scene, doesnt work in another

Tags: texturing, game-engine

The same exactly image of the owl is rendered in Reward scene and is not rendering in HUD Screen for overlaying Scene

The same GLSL mode! The same plane and the same material. why it doesnt work?

[image]

[image]

Comment: In material tab set emit to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used that GIF that solved the problem:

https://gifyu.com/image/TPTA